# trouble activating bootstrap dropdown in navbar on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am trying to create a mockup of a website using bootstrap nav dropdowns. I am still new to this and I have read through posts about this and tried various edits, but my dropdown is still not activating when I click it.  Any suggestions or pointers would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/allisoncodes/sdywsaf4/10/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="btn btn-default">
    <a href="#home">
      <icon class="fa fa-home"></icon>
    </a>
  </button>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Community
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-toggle="tab">Recent Activity</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-toggle="tab">Member Forum</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-toggle="tab">Member List</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#" data-toggle="tab">Member Groups</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn btn-default">
    <a href="#">Pet Help</a></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="#">Pets For Sale</a></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><a href="#">Pets Services</a></button>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('[data-toggle=tab]').hover(function (e) {
  $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: You may be missing jQuery (it's not used in your jsfiddle). See [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included) and please be specific about what "not working" means.

Comment: Try incorporating jQuery in your fiddle, here's a working example - your code works! [https://jsfiddle.net/sdywsaf4/11/](https://jsfiddle.net/sdywsaf4/11/)

Comment: Add the jquery.js library (https://jquery.com/) to your code and make sure it's above your jquery statement. (It's probably best to put that all at the bottom of your page as well.)

Comment: Thank you everyone. I had previously incorporated jQuery in my fiddle, but for some reason that edit didn't save and I did not notice the error. It's working now!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my code was correct, I had just forgotten to include the jQuery CDN. Thanks for the help!